# how to handle box bounding result of YOLOv2

Tags: python, yolo, darkflow

Sorry for my limited knowledge of AI. But I'm trying to use YOLOv2 (specifically darkflow) to identify my object. I have 100 images and have trained with 1000 epochs. However, my output is not really what the instructions I read online. There are too many bouding boxes to appear and I only have one object to identify in the picture. This is my test file. Also I would like to know the effect of 'threshold' in 'options'. Where is my problem currently located? Please let me know.

```py
from darkflow.net.build import TFNet
import numpy as np
import cv2
import time
import pprint as pp

options = {
            "model": "cfg/yolov2-voc-1c.cfg",
            "load": -1,
            "threshold": 0.01
        }

tfnet2 = TFNet(options)

tfnet2.load_from_ckpt()

def boxing(original_img, predictions):
    newImage = np.copy(original_img)

    for result in predictions:
        top_x = result['topleft']['x']
        top_y = result['topleft']['y']

        btm_x = result['bottomright']['x']
        btm_y = result['bottomright']['y']

        confidence = result['confidence']
        label = result['label'] + " " + str(round(confidence, 3))

        if confidence > 0.06:
            newImage = cv2.rectangle(newImage, (top_x, top_y), (btm_x, btm_y), (255,0,0), 3)
            newImage = cv2.putText(newImage, label, (top_x, top_y-5), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_COMPLEX_SMALL , 0.8, (0, 230, 0), 1, cv2.LINE_AA)

    return newImage

original_img = cv2.imread("data_test.jpg")
original_img = cv2.cvtColor(original_img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
result = tfnet2.return_predict(original_img)

new_frame = boxing(original_img, result)

cv2.imwrite('output.jpg', new_frame)
```

Result image:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You are using a very low Threshold =0.01 it means that the model will consider that it detected an object if the probability is above 1% , usually we use a Threshold value bigger than 25%.
Also consider changing the confidence.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Perhaps because the threshold is too low, the result is a lot of bouding boxes. Do you have any way to correct this case? Because if to threshold = 0.1, no bouding boxes in the result